# Scrolling through jQuery UI Draggables on Touch Devices Triggers Drag

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, touch, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm using jQuery UI's draggables and droppables functionality. To make it work on touch devices, I'm using jQuery UI Touch Punch.

I have a list of draggables that don't have much space around them. On touch devices, I found that the only way to scroll through the list was to use the very narrow spaces around the draggables, which isn't user friendly. I thought about adding buttons to scroll up and down, but I think that would likely feel foreign and clunky to users who are used to scrolling with swipes. I ended up with kind of a hacky workaround, but it has two issues:

1. It takes a while before the swipe starts to scroll, which might give
   the false impression that the website is lagging.
2. There is no kinetic aspect to the scrolling, so it's a lot more work
   to scroll than usual.

## My Question

Can my code be improved to fix the above two issues or should I be taking an entirely different approach to fixing this problem?

## The Code

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PX8rv/) • [full screen result of jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PX8rv/embedded/result/)

**HTML**

```
<p>Drag the colored squares into the gray area on the right.</p>

<ul>
    <li><span class="red"></span></li>
    <li><span class="orange"></span></li>
    <li><span class="yellow"></span></li>
    <li><span class="green"></span></li>
    <li><span class="blue"></span></li>
    <li><span class="purple"></span></li>
    <li><span class="red"></span></li>
    <li><span class="orange"></span></li>
    <li><span class="yellow"></span></li>
    <li><span class="green"></span></li>
    <li><span class="blue"></span></li>
    <li><span class="purple"></span></li>
    <li><span class="red"></span></li>
    <li><span class="orange"></span></li>
    <li><span class="yellow"></span></li>
    <li><span class="green"></span></li>
    <li><span class="blue"></span></li>
    <li><span class="purple"></span></li>
    <li><span class="red"></span></li>
    <li><span class="orange"></span></li>
    <li><span class="yellow"></span></li>
    <li><span class="green"></span></li>
    <li><span class="blue"></span></li>
    <li><span class="purple"></span></li>
</ul>

<div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
p {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

ul, div {
    float: left;
    height: 440px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

ul {
    width: 127px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    list-style: none;
}

li span {
    margin: 9px auto;
}

span {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 5px solid #000;
}

.red {
    background-color: #f00;
}

.orange {
    background-color: #ff8000;
}

.yellow {
    background-color: #ff0;
}

.green {
    background-color: #0f0;
}

.blue {
    background-color: #00f;
}

.purple {
    background-color: #f0f;
}

div {
    width: 330px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

div span {
    float: left;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
// BEGIN: My attempt to fix the scrolling issue on touch devices

if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) {
    $('span').on('dragstart', function(e) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('scroll')) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }).on('mousemove', function(e) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('scroll')) {
            $('ul').scrollTop(scroll_top_on_mousedown + mousedown_coords.pageY - e.pageY);
            return false;
        }

        if (typeof(mousedown_coords) == 'object' && Math.max(
                Math.abs(mousedown_coords.pageX - e.pageX),
                Math.abs(mousedown_coords.pageY - e.pageY)
            ) >= 80
        ) {
            if (e.pageX - mousedown_coords.pageX < 70) {
                $(this).addClass('scroll');
            }
        }
    }).on('mousedown', function(e) {
        mousedown_coords = {
            'pageX': e.pageX,
            'pageY': e.pageY,
        };

        scroll_top_on_mousedown = $('ul').scrollTop();
    }).on('touchend', function() {
        $(this).trigger('mouseup'); // Android fix

        delete window.mousedown_coords;
        $('ul .scroll').removeClass('scroll');
    });
}

// END: My attempt to fix the scrolling issue on touch devices

$('span').draggable({
    distance: 90,
    helper: 'clone',
    containment: $('div')
});

$('div').droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        if ($(this).children('span').length == 12) {
            $(this).empty();
        }

        $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone());
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to add a **[delay option](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-delay)** in your draggable function? If you set a delay of, say 500 milliseconds, maybe it will be enough to let the user scroll the page without triggering the draggable  function?

Comment: @Cholesterol If I rip out all the code I wrote that fakes the scroll and then add the `delay` option, I'm back to where I was before (only being able to scroll if my finger is on part of the gray area outside of the colored squares), the difference being that there is now a delay before the colored squares are dragged, of course. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I think the best answer is to rethink your UI. Forcing a user to scroll over draggable elements is just going to present problems. At first I thought using jQuery's `tabhold` event would work to delay the `draggable` event but they don't want to play nice together.

Comment: I ended up coming to the same conclusion, so I made it so that on touch devices, the user must tap on the item before it becomes draggable. I added a visual cue that it is draggable so that it's obvious to the user. After the user drags it over, or if they change their mind and tap on the same item again or tap on a different item, it becomes undraggable again.

Comment: Could you please share what you did with us? I am having a similar problem as well :(

Comment: @GETah Is there a part of my previous comment that you're stuck on?

Comment: @Nick Thanks for the quick reply. I am thinking to implement the same thing as you did, on a mobile device, you will need to tap first before dragging and dropping items.

Comment: @GETah If you're having a hard time getting started, I would recommend posting a Stack Overflow question. I might be able to help out and if I can't, somebody else will, I'm sure.